# Cannot access AMAZON REDSHIFT using boto3.resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, boto3, infrastructure-as-code

I am currently learning about boto3 and how it can interact with AWS to connect using both the client and resources methods. I was made to understand that it doesnt matter which one I use that I can still get access except in some cases where I would need to access some client features that are not available through the resources medium hence I would specifiy the created resource variable i.e from

```
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
```

Hence if there is a need for me to access some client features, I would simply specify

```
s3.resource.meta.client
```

**But the main issue here is, I tried creating clients/resources first for EC2, S3, IAM, and Redshift** so I did this

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', 
                    region_name='us-west-2', 
                    aws_access_key_id=KEY, 
                    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET)

s3 = boto3.resource('s3', 
                    region_name='us-west-2', 
                    aws_access_key_id=KEY, 
                    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET)
 
iam = boto3.client('iam', 
                    region_name='us-west-2', 
                    aws_access_key_id=KEY, 
                    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET)

redshift = boto3.resource('redshift', 
                    region_name='us-west-2', 
                    aws_access_key_id=KEY, 
                    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET)
```

**But I get this error**

```
UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'redshift'. Valid service names are: cloudformation, cloudwatch, dynamodb, ec2, glacier, iam, opsworks, s3, sns, sqs

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
   - s3
   - sns
   - sqs

Consider using a boto3.client('redshift') instead of a resource for 'redshift'
```

**Please why is that, I thought I could create using the commands that I specified, Please help**

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you consult the [Boto3 documentation for Amazon Redshift](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/redshift.html). It does, indeed, show that there is **no resource method** for Redshift (or Redshift Data API, or Redshift Serverless).

Also, I recommend against using `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` in your code unless there is a specific need (such as extracting them from Environment Variables). It is better to use the AWS CLI `aws configure` command to store AWS credentials in a configuration file, which will be automatically accessed by AWS SDKs such as boto3.

Comment: Thank you @John Rotenstein